# How to get the function definition from an object?

Tags: python

Suppose we have following code defined in tester.py

```
class Tester( object ):
    def method( self ):
        print 'I am a Tester'
```

and we have following defined in main.py

```
from tester import Tester
t = Tester()
#print definition of t
```

is there anyway we could get the definitions of a class/function from an object in a systematic way? or we have to parse the code and extract the code definition manually then save them into a string?

Comment: You might want to explain the bigger goal you're trying to achieve, since there's probably a better way to do it than whatever you've got in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect

class Tester( object ):
    def method( self ):
        print 'I am a Tester'

print inspect.getsource(Tester)
```

Output:

```
class Tester( object ):
    def method( self ):
        print 'I am a Tester'
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  Good answer.